# How to filter a data set by a different date on each row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data set of student records, including their school start date and exit date. I have another data set that includes every date of the current school year. I would like to join the two data sets so that I can see how many students were enrolled, and will be enrolled, on every day of the year.

I am running this query in Google Bigquery, where it does not allow a subquery in the SELECT clause.

Currently I'm just using a Google Sheet that has a different formula in each cell, but that's not a great solution. I want to move this into Bigquery, and my hunch is that it can be done with a recursive WITH clause, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few solutions to your problem in BigQuery. Here are two different approaches:

1. An inefficient one would be to join each student with all the rows in your calendar table:

```
SELECT * FROM
  studentTable
  JOIN
  calendarTable
  ON
  true
WHERE
student_start_date <= calendar_date AND student_end_date >= calendar_date
```

And then group by the calendar_date and count the number of students.

2. A more efficient approach without joining to the calendar table would be to generate a date array for each student using their start and end date and then unnesting on the date field.

This works if the "calendar table" has all the dates between the start and end date. If not, you can still filter to only those dates at the end.

```
WITH dummyData AS (
  SELECT
    "A" as student, DATE(2022, 1, 1) as startDate, DATE(2022, 1, 31) as endDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    "B" as student, DATE(2022, 1, 4) as startDate, DATE(2022, 1, 15) as endDate
),

addDaysPresent as (
SELECT *, GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(startDate, endDate) datesPresent FROM dummyData)

SELECT dp, count(*) FROM addDaysPresent, unnest (datesPresent) as dp GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1
```